# Rust temporary variable lifetime in method chaining

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn Rust's lifetime rules by comparing it to similar concepts in C++, which I'm more familiar with. Most of the time, my intuition works really well and I can make sense the rule. However, in the following case, I'm not sure if my understanding is correct or not.

In Rust, a temporary value's lifetime is the end of its statement, except when the last temporary value is bound to a name using `let`.

```rust
struct A(u8);
struct B(u8);

impl A {
    fn get_b(&mut self) -> Option<B> {
        Some(B(self.0))
    }
}

fn a(v: u8) -> A {
    A(v)
}

// temporary A's lifetime is the end of the statement
// temporary B binds to a name so lives until the enclosing block
let b = a(1).get_b();

// temporary A's lifetime is the end of the statement
// temporary B's lifetime extends to the enclosing block,
// so that taking reference of temporary works similar as above
let b = &a(2).get_b();
```

If the temporary value is in an `if` condition, according to the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions.html#temporary-lifetimes), the lifetime is instead limited to the conditional expression.

```rust
// Both temporary A and temporary B drops before printing some
if a(3).get_b().unwrap().val <= 3 {
    println!("some");
}
```

#### Now to the question:

If putting `let` in `if` condition, because of pattern matching, we are binding to the inner part of the temporary value. I'd expect the temporary value bound by `let` to be extended to the enclosing block, while other temporary values should still have a lifetime limited by the if condition.

*(In this case actually everything is copied I would say even temporary B can be dropped, but that's a separate question.)*

However, both temporaries' lifetimes are extended to the enclosing `if` block.

```rust
// Both temporary A and temporary B's lifetime are extended to the end of the enclosing block,
// which is the if statement
if let Some(B(v @ 0...4)) = a(4).get_b() {
    println!("some {}", v);
}
```

Should this be considered an inconsistency in Rust? Or am I misunderstanding and there is a consistent rule that can explain this behavior?

#### Full code example:

- [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=f7837817f7552b2b5f3e7fd5a6768135)
- The same thing implemented in [C++](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5LTbZfbYRnaj194S) that matches my expectation

Note the output from Rust is

```
some 4
Drop B 4
Drop A 4
```

while the output from C++ is

```
Drop A 4                                                                                                                                                                         
some 4                                                                                                                                                                           
Drop B 4
```

I have read this Reddit [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/6dynjz/psa_temporaries_in_final_expression_in_block_live/) and Rust [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37612), which I think is quite relevant, but I still can't find a clear set of lifetime rule that works for all the cases in Rust.

#### Update:

What I'm unclear about is why the temporary lifetime rule about `if` conditional expression does *not* apply to `if let`. I think the `let Some(B(v @ 0...4)) = a(4).get_b()` should be the conditional expression, and thus the temporary A's lifetime should be limited by that, rather than the entire `if` statement.

The behaviour of extending temporary B's lifetime to the entire `if` statement is expected, because that is borrowed by the pattern matching.

Comment: you borrow `&mut self`, so I expect this result, try by consume `self` => `get_b(self)`

Comment: @Stargateur `get_b` does borrow `&mut self`, but the return value doesn't contain a lifetime, so it doesn't need to "stay borrowed". I think what's happening here is the compiler considers the entire `if let` expression "the current statement" (i.e., it doesn't work the same way as `let tmp = a(4).get_b(); if let Some(B(_)) = tmp { ... }` which would have the same output as the similar C++ code.)

Comment: @trentcl The issue explain why, https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37612#issuecomment-304626464, pattern matching extend the borrow to the scope of the pattern matching. `let b = a(4).get_b();
    if let Some(B(v@ 0...4)) = b {
        println!("some {}", v);
    }` should work as expected.

Comment: It's not that the *borrow* is extended, but the lifetime of the temporary is extended even though it *isn't* borrowed. At least that's my interpretation

Comment: @Stargateur if `get_b` consumes `self`, then that's a different situation. Temporary A will be dropped inside `get_b` body because it is moved there. That's not the same effect as dropping at the end of the statement.

Comment: @Stargateur I'm aware of that issue. And I understand the borrow would be extended by the pattern matching. However, as @trentcl said, the borrow here is `Option<B>`. Temporary A should not be extended as it is not borrowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `if let` construct is just syntactic sugar for a `match` construct. `let Some(B(v @ 0...4)) = a(4).get_b()` is not a conditional used in a regular `if` expression, because it is not an expression that evaluates to `bool`. Given your example:

```
if let Some(B(v @ 0...4)) = a(4).get_b() {
    println!("some {}", v);
}
```

It will behave exactly the same as the below example. No exceptions. `if let` is rewritten into `match` before the type or borrow checkers are even run.

```
match a(4).get_b() {
    Some(B(v @ 0...4)) => {
        println!("some {}", v);
    }
    _ => {}
}
```

Temporaries live as long as they do in match blocks because they sometimes come in handy. Like if your last function was `fn get_b(&mut self) -> Option<&B>`, and if the temporary didn't live for the entire match block, then it wouldn't pass borrowck.

If conditionals don't follow the same rule because it's impossible for the last function call in an if conditional to hold a reference to anything. They have to evaluate to a plain `bool`.

See:

- [Rust issue 37612](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37612)