Match lock deals with deadlocks caused by long-term tasks
I am confused by the results of running the following code. I can understand the logic of the behavior, but it seems a bit unreasonable to me (because I think it makes the variable lifetime confusing)
Can anyone tell me the benefit of this behavior?
fn func_2() {
    let vec = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::<u8>::new()));

    let thread_vec = vec.clone();
    let t1 = thread::spawn(move ||
    {
        let vec = thread_vec;
        loop {
            match vec.lock().unwrap().pop() {
                Some(value) => {
                    println!("{:?} pop: {}", thread::current().id(), value);
                    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000 * 30));
                },
                None => {
                    println!("{:?} pop: nullptr", thread::current().id());
                    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000 * 30));
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    });

    let thread_vec = vec.clone();
    let t2 = thread::spawn(move ||
    {
        let vec = thread_vec;
        loop {
            match vec.lock().unwrap().pop() {
                Some(value) => {
                    println!("{:?} pop: {}", thread::current().id(), value);
                    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000 * 30));
                },
                None => {
                    println!("{:?} pop: nullptr", thread::current().id());
                    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000 * 30));
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    });


    t1.join().unwrap();
    t2.join().unwrap();
}

The above code will continue to acquire the lock when a thread enters thread::sleep(), but my first thought is that it should get the result of pop() first, and then because the object used for matching is the obtained result, the lock has been released before matching.
The following code is normal
fn func_2() {
    let vec = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::<u8>::new()));

    let thread_vec = vec.clone();
    let t1 = thread::spawn(move ||
    {
        let vec = thread_vec;
        loop {
            let result = vec.lock().unwrap().pop();
            match result {
                Some(value) => {
                    println!("{:?} pop: {}", thread::current().id(), value);
                    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000 * 30));
                },
                None => {
                    println!("{:?} pop: nullptr", thread::current().id());
                    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000 * 30));
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    });

    let thread_vec = vec.clone();
    let t2 = thread::spawn(move ||
    {
        let vec = thread_vec;
        loop {
            let result = vec.lock().unwrap().pop();
            match result {
                Some(value) => {
                    println!("{:?} pop: {}", thread::current().id(), value);
                    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000 * 30));
                },
                None => {
                    println!("{:?} pop: nullptr", thread::current().id());
                    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000 * 30));
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    });


    t1.join().unwrap();
    t2.join().unwrap();
}

I think he divided the code of vec.lock().unwrap().pop() and match into the same variable life cycle. I don't know if this is reasonable, so I want to ask for your opinions.
I personally think the behavior logic of these two codes should be consistent, but the current performance can also be understood
Below is my environment information
cargo 1.82.0 (8f40fc59f 2024-08-21)
release: 1.82.0
commit-hash: 8f40fc59fb0c8df91c97405785197f3c630304ea
commit-date: 2024-08-21
host: x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
libgit2: 1.8.1 (sys:0.19.0 vendored)
libcurl: 8.9.0-DEV (sys:0.4.74+curl-8.9.0 vendored ssl:Schannel)
os: Windows 10.0.19045 (Windows 10 Pro) [64-bit]


Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55292164/rust-temporary-variable-lifetime-in-method-chaining

match vec.lock().unwrap().pop() { // <- scope starts here
   // ...
} // <- scope ends here

In the first example the entire match statement forms a single scope, when you acquire the guard it lives for the entire scope and dropped at the end of match statement. So in the match arms you are still holding the lock, although there's no explicit variable, to which it's bound.
let result = vec.lock().unwrap().pop(); // <- scope starts and ends here
match result { // <- start of another scope
// ...
}

in the second example, the statement acquiring the lock ends before the match statement, and as such the lock is released (the guard is dropped) before the match arms are reached.
In rust, the compiler automatically inserts drop calls at the end of scope where the value was created or moved. Consider this for example:
fn main() {
    let string = "some random text".to_string(); // <- string comes into first scope
    {
        // start of another scope, string is moved into it
        string
    }; //  end of scope, string dropped here

    // println!("{string}"); // this will not compile, string has been dropped
}

regarding the consistency you mentioned, it is consistent, compiler inserts drop invocations in a deterministic manner at the end of each scope which owns the value.
